# Closure Syntax with and without parameters

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, closures

iOS 13, Swift 5

I am trying get my head around closure syntax in Swift and almost there. I got the first three bon, and understand them; but the last no. How do I call self.theMethod4 here? the syntax shown is wrong!

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
      .onAppear {
        self.theMethod {
          print("1")
        }
        self.the2Method("Ya ") {
          print("1")
        }
        self.the3Method("Hello") {arg2do in
          print("1 ",arg2do)
        }
        self.the4Method("World") { (arg2do) -> String in
          print("1 ",arg2do)
        }
      }
}

func theMethod(_ endOfMethod: @escaping () -> Void) {
  print("2")
  endOfMethod()
}

func the2Method(_ arg1:String, endOfMethod: @escaping () -> Void) {
  print("3")
  endOfMethod()
}

func the3Method(_ arg1:String, endOfMethod: @escaping (_ arg2:String) -> Void) {
  print("4")
  endOfMethod("Yo")
}

func the4Method(_ arg1:String, endOfMethod: @escaping (_ arg2: String) -> String) {
  print("5")
  let an = endOfMethod("Pe")
  print("An ",an)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure in method 4 is defined to return a string, so when you call it, that’s what you’d have to do:

```
self.the4Method("World") { arg2do -> String in
    return "1 " + arg2do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got the closure syntax (`{ (parameters) -> ReturnValueType in statements }`) right, but since the fourth method needs a closure that returns a `String`, you need to return a string.

For example, this:

```
self.the4Method("World") { (arg2do) -> String in
    print("1 ",arg2do)
    return "return value"
}
```

prints:

```
5
1  Pe
An  return value
```

Explanation of the output:

First the body of `the4Method` gets run, so `5` gets printed. Then `the4Method` calls `endOfMethod`, which is the closure passed in, with the argument `"Pe"`. So `print("1 ", "Pe")` gets run, causing the second line to be printed. After that, the closure returns `"return value"` and we are now back to `the4Method`. The return value gets assigned to `an`, and `print("An ",an)` is run, causing the last line to be printed.